# Python multi threading exiting worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

So I have the main thread spawning worker threads that have infinite loops to deal with system monitoring.  So it looks something like this

```
while True:
     Check_server_status( host )
     wait( *minutes* )
```

This worker thread should run forever because we need to constantly monitor the servers and each thread is currently monitoring one machine but I may scale it so each thread has a list of servers to check on.  Also, each thread is writing to a csv file the information that it is finding.

The main thread just calls this thread for each host that it finds in a list.

```
hosts = [a,b]
threads = []
for host in hosts:
     t = worker( host )
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()
     threads.append( t )
```

I am trying to make this script exit cleanly on ctrl-c.  So I want to make sure that the files are closed and that the threads exits.  Is there any good way to handle this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: For every host, separate CSV is created or one common CSV is used to write information?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, `daemon` threads terminated by the main thread ending aren't cleaned up properly, so avoid that.

And `KeyboardInterrupt` isn't necessarily delivered to the main thread, or to any specific thread, so it's probably not best to rely on Python's default handler for `SIGINT` here, but instead write your own handler to replace it.

Probably the simplest approach is to have all the threads loop on a shared `threading.Event` object, looping based on a `.wait(*seconds*)` call (so your per loop sleep is folded into the `while` condition, and you can still exit immediately, anytime during the wait).

So you might do:

```
import threading

shouldexit = threading.Event()
```

Then your worker functions would be of the form:

```
def worker(host):
    while not shouldexit.wait(minutes * 60):
        Check_server_status( host )
```

They'd all be launched without setting them as `daemon`s, and you'd register a `SIGINT` handler like this one:

```
import signal

def ctrlchandler(signum, frame):
    print('User triggered quit')
    shouldexit.set()

# Set the signal handlers for the Ctrl-C related events
if hasattr(signal, 'CTRL_C_EVENT'):
    # Only on Windows
    signal.signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, ctrlchandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrlchandler)
```

Ideally, there would be no living main thread to kill off in this case (all threads would be looping on the shared `Event`, with the main thread exiting after launching the workers); if that's not the case, you'd need to figure out some way of terminating the main thread.

One approach might be to store off the default handler for `SIGINT` when you register your replacement handler, have your handler `join` all the worker threads after setting the `Event`, then explicitly invoke the original `SIGINT` handler so `KeyboardInterrupt` fires in a surviving thread as normal and cleans up the now workerless main thread.